# Prove generating function of $a_n = (b+1)^n - b^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, generating-functions

The problem is prove that $$\frac{x}{(1-bx)(1-bx-x)}$$
is the generating function for the sequence $$a_n = (b+1)^n - b^n$$
I tried separating the fraction as $$x\frac{1}{1-bx}\frac{1}{1-x(b+1)}$$
which yields the generating functions $$x\sum_{n=0}^\infty (bx)^n\sum_{n=0}^\infty ((b+1)x)^n$$
Did I make a mistake? If not, how does this lead to the generating function with terms $a_n$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**
$$
\begin{split}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n
 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (b+1)^nx^n - \sum_{n=0}^\infty b^n x^n
 = \frac{1}{1-x(b+1)} - \frac{1}{1-xb}
\end{split}
$$

Comment: I understand how that works, but where did I go wrong with the method I used?

Comment: @Vahan the standard way would be to decompose the function using partial fractions, then you immediately end up with my decomposition, but going from right to left. Your way is more painful since you have to multiply 2 power series together and likely cancel the telescoping series of coefficients to arrive at the same result.

Answer (score 1):

There is no mistake with your approach. The calculation is just, let's say slightly  more cumbersome.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{x\sum_{k=0}^\infty}&\color{blue}{ (bx)^k\sum_{l=0}^\infty ((b+1)x)^l}\\
> &=x\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{{k+l=n}\atop{k,l\geq 0}}b^k(b+1)^l\right)x^n\tag{1}\\
> &=x\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=0}^n b^k(b+1)^{n-k}\right)x^n\\
> &=x\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\left(\frac{b}{b+1}\right)^k\right)(b+1)^nx^n\tag{2}\\
> &=x\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1-\left(\frac{b}{b+1}\right)^{n+1}}{1-\frac{b}{b+1}}\right)(b+1)^nx^n\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(1-\left(\frac{b}{b+1}\right)^{n+1}\right)(b+1)^{n+1}x^{n+1}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left((b+1)^{n+1}-b^{n+1}\right)x^{n+1}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left((b+1)^{n}-b^{n}\right)x^{n}}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the Cauchy product of two series.
- In (2) we do some rearrangements as preparation for the next step.
- In (3) we apply the *[geometric series formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula)*.

Comment: You're right, that is more cumbersome. But thank you for the detailed explanation.

Comment: @Vahan: You're welcome.